# ActionbarSherlock SearchView not close in onCloseListener

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview, android-search, oncloselistener

I have implemented `onCloseListener` of `SearchView`. I want to close `SearchView` Programmatically that i have done using following code. but its not working for me.

If i use `searchView.setIconified(true);` for closing `searchView` after updating data, run infinite times.

```
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            searchString = "";

            if (bindingProducts()) {
                 HIDE ERROR MSG 
                (findViewById(R.id.productIfNoAvailable)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                  SHOW ERROR MSG 
                (findViewById(R.id.productIfNoAvailable)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            searchView.setIconified(true);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

How can i close after updating View?

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let the `onClose` return true it means that you are consuming the close event. If you return false the system will close the `SearchView` for you.

Comment: Thanks man, I have change `return false;` and its working fine.